# "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors

I'm serving an Angular app from localhost:8000 and a node backend from localhost:3000. I have a single $http.get run on page load and my frontend logs

`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`

There are multiple SO posts on this but they all say "Don't open your file directly in the browser" and I am serving them all, not opening them.

My backend is configured for CORS and the routes work when hitting them via Postman.

Frontend:

[image: controller]

Backend:

[image: Backend]

Error:

[image]

The `host + '/'` is just a constant that references "localhost:3000"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your URL is missing the scheme (`http:`). You are trying to use a relative URL, which is resolving to something like `file:///blah/blah/blah/localhost:3000` … and as the error message says, you can't load data from `file:` URLs as CORS isn't supported there. Use the right URL.